# Horizontal scroller with post_thumbnail's

Tags: jquery, post-thumbnails

Attempting to create a horizontal scroller using post_thumbnail's.

I've made a filterable portfolio section using this tutorial: http://www.wearepixel8.com/blog/filterable-portfolio but my attempts to make it a horizontal scroller have failed, i've tried several different jQuery image scroller plugins to attempt it but none have worked.

Can anyone give advice on how to achieve what i'm looking to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it on a few sites. An example is below. If you want the jQuery code for it, I can give it you. It is a list of post thumbnails with their post titles shown below them.
[paragonhondainfo.com](http://www.paragonhondainfo.com)

Comment: That would be awesome! You'd think someone would of made a tutorial on how to do this for wordpress already. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Loop code - http://pastebin.com/NzJX5G4R, scroller function - http://pastebin.com/5aqDHA74, and the call to the function - http://pastebin.com/1qWBGFwr.

Comment: here is the original which I modified to fit my wordpress needs. http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-infinite-carousel/

Comment: Works wonderfully after a little finessing (which is expected). Now to figure out the glitch in the filtering! Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

[Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html) is quite usable: Good examples, clear documentation. You have to move some CSS rules into your script tough to keep everything working for people without JavaScript.
I did that just last night. :) Took more time than expected, but the result is really smooth.